# Can an RSA OpenSSL key generated with C/C++ be decrypted with PHP?

Tags: php, c++, c, openssl, php-openssl

In a number of situations security software involves the interaction between (desktop) applications and web interfaces. For (RSA) asymmetric encryption we use the [C library](https://openssl.org) of OpenSSL (version 1.0.2d at present) and we use the openssl [PHP library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.openssl.php).

All the standard stuff:

- private encrypt (C++) data and public decrypt (PHP)
- public encrypt (C++) data and private decrypt (PHP)

works. And also the other way around: PHP -> C++ and C++ -> PHP

In addition generating an encrypted private key with PHP and decrypting that key with C/C++ also works. But not the other way around: I want to decrypt with PHP a private key that is generated and encrypted with C++. Note: this is different from encrypting/decrypting data with the keys.

The problem seems to be the way C OpenSSL encrypts a private key. It is not enough to know the algorithm with which the key is encrypted (aes-256-cbc in our case). The password is also stretched. The way the key is encrypted by OpenSSL has changed over time. I will give an example how it looks now.

Part of the the header of the private key generated with OpenSSL C/C++ looks like:

```
-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
MIISnzBJBgkqhkiG9w0BBQ0wPDAbBgkqhkiG9w0BBQwwDgQI/epYUO8+LygCAggA
```

Whereas part of the header of a pem-encoded private key generated with openssl PHP looks like:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: DES-EDE3-CBC,372DA3A61BEB36AA

bc9NsTtdfcMW9t9isDPgl86aME223ockk9pIGDduEyrTS7zh1gwHWSWnD2efbxLd
```

I have tried to use some PHP extensions, like [phpseclib](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/), but I still cannot use a private key generated with C OpenSSL in PHP programs. The public keys are not encrypted and they can be exchanged between the two languages without any problem.

For generating RSA keys with C OpenSSL we use the EVP_PKEY structure.

**Edited by author on August 12, 2015**

In reply to neubert  I have generated an encrypted private RSA key with the OpenSSL utility "openssl genpkey":

```
OpenSSL> genpkey -algorithm RSA -out c:\temp\test512.pem -aes-256-cbc -pass pass:1234 -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:512
```

So key length is 512 bits and password "1234".

To get the unencrypted form of the key I used "openssl pkey":

```
OpenSSL> pkey -in c:\temp\test512.pem  -out c:\temp\test512naked.pem
```

Note on Windows the openssl executable is called "openssl.exe".

Here are the keys:

```
-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
```

and

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIBVAIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCAT4wggE6AgEAAkEAqxGy/AXwTEvx+moN
eRMNO/bWYBE+dX7kNROzswC2SzO6+NgYqKKIkYb8+Iho2ssuoYVWc62Gk37gxEhi
QrIDRQIDAQABAkEAlsA1I0S0evfeGNfGYbC5U+N1DRmFGhOlVWS0UgVJn8BYIpQI
fjseZ3xXhtfZypzTzc9VZKUJedi3cv7Ju9gqYQIhANzE+XbiytUzBFTzKuRanMEn
o6noJDGiaVktWvbbZEkpAiEAxl5VedZ1PCU5Qpd+1u7agIZfSBwWnkI0nnxO5Slo
AL0CIEWc0rCbGKwbVx1WQ8sXi2AYmLHFokwIU0GsXIeEbF3pAiALvbOjdX0U5UMh
XOQmBpcqOknTc84m6dZBdywYRj4gpQIgfg/KLv7cv/mGoe8tvh3geYTpnZ2HRwDN
O9Kal0WOaiw=
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Answer (score 1):

The `-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----` key is PKCS8 encoded. The symmetric cipher being used (and the IV) is embedded in the key. phpseclib currently only supports pbeWithMD5AndDES-CBC. The pbe part means that it's using PBKDF1. Maybe that's what your key is using, too, hard to say.

Basically, if you can generate another identical key and post it - along with the password to unlock it - that'd be helpful. I can add support to that cipher / pbkdf to phpseclib.

If you want to try modifying phpseclib yourself feel free to do so. Check the following switch statement:

https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/1.0.0/phpseclib/Crypt/RSA.php#L1225

But like I said, tho - I can do it too - I just need you to provide the key (or an identically formatted one!)